# how to run module at specific location without setting PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python

I have some module tree (modules and submodules).
A certain "main.py" belongs to the same directory structure and uses some other modules from the tree. So I need to have my module tree root in sys.path variable. 
From the other side: I'd like to call "main.py" from another location (being in another current directory on my command prompt). Is it possible to call someting like

`python3 -m submodule.main`

but with additional structure root directory specification and without the need to set PYTHONPATH?

Comment: The only working solution that I found is to modify PYTHONPATH in program's private environment, but I don't like it:

env "PYTHONPATH=modulesroot:$PYTHONPATH" -m submodule.main

Answer (score 0):

This *SHOULD* work. It won't neccessarily be fast, but in theory it will work.

```
import os
os.chdir("C:/path/To/directory/That/contains/The/module(s)")
import module1
os.chdir("C:/path/To/directory/That/contains/The/module(s)2")
import module2.submod1
os.chdir("C:/path/To/directory/That/contains/The/module(s)3")
from module3.submod2 import *
<rest_of_code>
```